# Authenticating to S3 from Meteor Mobile Application

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, meteor, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I have a Meteor Mobile app that accesses a lot of photos stored in my S3 bucket. These photos are user uploaded and change frequently. I don't want these photos to be accessible to anyone that isn't using my app. (ie: these photos are only viewable from my application and going to the url directly in a browser won't load them).

What is the best way to accomplish this? AWS Cognito seems to be the logical choice, but it doesn't seem easy to implement and I'm not exactly sure how to authenticate to AWS from the client once it gets a Cognito identity.

My other thought was putting a read only AWS Key on every url and authenticating that way, but that's almost pointless. It would be really easy to find out the key and secret.

**EDIT:**

To be specific, the URLs for the images are in a Mongo collection and I pass them into a template. So, the S3 resources are just loaded up with an image tag (`<img src="`). Something like AWS STS sounds like a great option, but I don't know of a way to pass the tokens in the headers when I'm loading them like this. Doing them as a pre-signed query string seems inefficient.

Another option is to restrict access with the `referrer` header, [like this issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4770). But like Martijn said, it isn't really a secure way of doing it.

Comment: In your app, are S3 image accesses authenticated? If they are, you can grant access to that authenticated GET, and deny any public access to your bucket

Comment: No, right now they are just publicly available images while in development, but I don't want that in production. I don't really know of a way to do authentication from the client besides passing the key and secret in the the url or in the header, which both can be seen. I guess passing in the header would be better than URL but not a solid solution.

Comment: No you definitely don't want to pass around the keys,  however you can use the Meteor server to send a http authentication request (which is not visible from the browser), to get an authentication token (I think) which you can pass in the image GET requests

Comment: Yeah that's a good idea, are you meaning like using AWS STS to get temporary tokens?

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact details, but that's the idea, I'll let you chase it to the end :)

Comment: STS does seem to be the way to go, but actually using the tokens is the hard part. I would like to just pass them in the headers like you said, but how I use the S3 images is just with a URL in the HTML. I have the URL of the image in Mongo and I just pass it into the template. So it's just an `<img src="`. You could use query strings, but you have to generate the signature of the URL, which seems inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and testing I solved this myself. My ultimate solution was to use the `referer` header to limit access to my S3 bucket. I created a more secure and detailed solution (see below), but it came with a performance hit that wouldn't work for my app. My app is based around viewing photos and videos, and not being able to have them load near instantly wasn't in the cards. Although, I feel like it could be a sufficient solution for most use-cases. Because my app isn't highly sensitive, the `referer` header is sufficient for me. [Here is how to use the http header `referer` to limit access to a bucket.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-4)

**Solution using Amazon's STS:**

First, you need to have the AWS SDK on both the [server](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/) and the [client.](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-browser/) There was no up to date packages for Meteor available, so I created my own. (I'll publish it shortly and put a link here once I do.)

On the server, you must use credentials that have the ability to assume a role. The role to be assumed must have a Trust Relationship with the user that is assuming the role. [Article on using IAM.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use.html) - [Article on using credentials with SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-configuring.html)

In the `server.js` file I created a Meteor Method that I can call from the client. It first checks if a user is logged in. If that's true, it checks to see if it's current temp-credentials are expiring in the next 5 minutes. If they are, I issue new credentials and either write them to the user document or return them as a callback. If they aren't expiring in the next 5 minutes, I return their current temp-credentials.

*You must use* `Meteor.bindEnvironment`*for the callback.* [See docs](https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html#bind-environment)

```
Meteor.methods({
'awsKey': function(){
  if (Meteor.userId()){
    var user = Meteor.userId();
    var now = moment(new Date());
    var userDoc = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: user});
    var expire = moment(userDoc.aws.expiration);
    var fiveMinutes = 5 * 60 * 1000;
    var fut = new Future();

    if(moment.duration(expire.diff(now))._milliseconds < fiveMinutes ){
        var params = {
            RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::556754141176:role/RoleToAssume',
            RoleSessionName: 'SessionName',
            DurationSeconds: 3600  //1 Hour
        };
        var sts = new AWS.STS();
        sts.assumeRole(params, Meteor.bindEnvironment((err, data) => {
            if (err){
                fut.throw(new Error(err));
            }else{
                Meteor.users.update({_id: user}, {$set: {aws: {accessKey: data.Credentials.AccessKeyId, secretKey: data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey, sessionToken: data.Credentials.SessionToken, expiration: data.Credentials.Expiration}}});
                fut.return(data.Credentials);
            }
          }));
          return fut.wait();
       }else{
         return userDoc.aws;
       }
      }
     }
    }
  });
```

Then you can invoke this method manually or in an `setInterval` on `Meteor.startup`.

```
  Meteor.setInterval(function(){
   if(Meteor.userId()){
      Meteor.call('awsKey', function(err, data){
        if (err){
          console.log(err);
        }else{
          if(data.accessKey){
            Session.set('accessKey', data.accessKey);
            Session.set('secretKey', data.secretKey);
            Session.set('sessionToken', data.sessionToken);
          }else{
            Session.set('accessKey', data.AccessKeyId);
            Session.set('secretKey', data.SecretAccessKey);
            Session.set('sessionToken', data.SessionToken);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }, 300000); //5 Minute interval
```

This way just sets the keys in a Session variable from the callback. You could do this by querying the user's document to get them as well.

Then, you can use these temporary credentials to get a signed URL for the object you are trying to access in your bucket.

I put this in a template helper by passing the object name to it in the template:

`{{getAwsUrl imageName}}`

```
Template.templateName.helpers({

     'getAwsUrl': function(filename){
         var accessKey = Session.get('accessKey');
         var secretKey = Session.get('secretKey');
         var sessionToken = Session.get('sessionToken');
         var filename = filename;
         var params = {Bucket: 'bucketName', Key: filename, Expires: 6000};
         new AWS.S3({accessKeyId: accessKey, secretAccessKey: secretKey, sessionToken: sessionToken, region: 'us-west-2'}).getSignedUrl('getObject', params, function (err, url) {
      if (err) {
         console.log("Error:" +err);
      }else{
         result = url;
      }
    });
     return result;
 }

});
```

That's all there is to it!  I'm sure this can be refined to be better, but this is just what I came up with in testing it really fast. Like I said, it should work in most use cases. My particular one didn't. For some reason, when you tried to toggle the `visibility: visible|hidden;` on an `img src` of these signedURLs they would take a lot longer to load than just setting the URL directly. It must be because Amazon has to decrypt the signed URL on their side before return the object.

Thanks to [Mikkel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3975309/mikkel) for the direction.